# MAMP - storing Database online?

Tags: mamp

I am wondering if it is possible while using MAMP to have the database online?

I am developing a couple sites locally between work and home, and initially thought I could get mamp to store or point to my external drive. No bueno.

SO am thinking I can still run mamp at work or at home pointing to my external drive but the DB that it would connect to  would be online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your system you could set up an SSH tunnel to another computer running the database.  SSH tunneling allows you to direct a port on your computer (For example port 8889 which MAMP uses by default for the MySQL port) to a port on another computer.  If set up correctly, you tell MAMP that you are using local port 8889, but ssh will then direct all traffic to the remote computer's mySQL port which is where you could run your database.  This [link](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) has a good tutorial on how to do this provided that you have ssh installed.

Comment: This works, but figured it was too much hassle :( Just created a testing environment, since it turns out to be the same thing.